# Examples of groups admitting a proper $1$-cocyle for a bounded representation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory, group-cohomology, unitary-representations

A representation $\pi: G \to B(H)$ of a group $G$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is called bounded iff $\sup_{g \in G} \| \pi(g) \|_{B(H)} = C < \infty$. A $1$-cocycle with respect to the representation $\pi$ is a map $\beta: G \to H$ such that
$$
  \beta(g \, h) = \beta(g) + \pi(g) \, \beta(h).
$$
In the recent preprint

> *Nishikawa, Shintaro*,
>   [**$\mathrm{Sp}(n,1)$ admits a proper $1$-cocycle for a uniformly
>   bounded representation**](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.03769), 
>   https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.03769.

It is claimed that $\mathrm{Sp}(1,n)$, although does not have the Haagerup approximation property, possess a metrically proper $1$-cocyle with respect to a bounded representation on a Hilbert space.

> **Question:** Are there other known examples of groups without the Haagerup property (or with property $\mathrm{(T)}$) which admit a proper
>   $1$-cocycler with respect to a bounded representation?

Comment: You automatically get their direct products (and direct product of their lattices), and subgroups of these direct products. Besides, I guess hyperbolic groups are natural candidates.